# Why is my webhook working on my local but not on production?

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, webserver

I am trying to set up a webhook for my project (Laravel 5.8, nginx on Production and XAMPP for local), whereby a service will send a POST payload to my desired url (/webhooks/revolut) when there is an update with a payment status.

I'm starting with the basics and have allowed a POST request to my URL (/webhooks/revolut) which would just return a JSON object with a success message.

I've created this in Laravel, by creating the POST route for the webhook, disabling CSRF verification for this one route and creating the webhook controller to return the JSON string.

When testing using Postman it works when using my local server, but once pushed live to my project, I am getting a "405 - Method Not Allowed" error (The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST). But I am sending a POST request to the server.

The Controller does not have any additional middleware on it and does  not require the user to be logged in to access the page. I am thinking this could be an authentication error though.

I have tried changing the URL (some forums said that trailing slashes can cause an issue) and Checking the middleware on the controller. I'm not sure what else I can try as from my 5 hour long search, there is little information on where to begin.

My route:

```
Route::post('/webhooks/revolut', 'Controller@webhookNotification')->name('api');
```

My Controller:

```
    public function webhookNotification(Request $request)
    {
      return response()->json([
          "message" => "API Successful."
      ], 201);
    }
```

My VerifyCRSF Middleware:

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Indicates whether the XSRF-TOKEN cookie should be set on the response.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $addHttpCookie = true;

    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        '/webhooks/revolut',
    ];
}
```

I'm confused as to why it is working on the local server but not the production. Could this be a nginx setup issue on the live server?

Comment: Make sure you don't have any redirects set up and that you're accessing it via the correct method. HTTP -> HTTPS redirects can mess up a request.

Comment: I'd like to see your Nginx config and the cURL request from postman that's failing.

Comment: Thanks guys - think this could be the issue. I've got a redirect on my server for HTTP requests:

`server {
    listen               80;
    listen               [::]:80;
    listen               443 ssl http2;
    listen               [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name          example.org;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/fullchain.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/privkey.pem;
    return 301 $scheme://www.example.org$request_uri;
}`

Comment: Banging my head against a chair right now; I needed to put the www. in front of the POST request since the nginx redirect was causing the issue.

Thanks for the help guys

Comment: Any luck getting this to work? I have a similar issue. Site works great, web hook throws a 403 error on production.